# AngularJS with nvD3 service not returning value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am new to AngularJS and d3. I have used this example: http://embed.plnkr.co/6t5bky/
and tried to create a 'bulletChart'.

my javascript file looks like below:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'bulletChart',
                transitionDuration: 500,
            }
        };

        $scope.data = populateData();

        function populateData(){

            /*return {
            "title": "Test Title",
            "subtitle": "Completed",
            "ranges": [200,400,700],
            "measures": [600],
            "markers": [300] 
            }*/

           return $http.get('http://myservice/data').then(function(response) {
                    console.log('response-dataNew',response.data);
                    return response;
                  ;})

                }

});
```

when I return the values as (commented in the code) , it works.

```
return {
            "title": "Test Title",
            "subtitle": "Completed",
            "ranges": [200,400,700],
            "measures": [600],
            "markers": [300] 
            }
```

and I see the bulletGraph:

[image]

When I try to use the service it gives me no graph. My service (http://myservice/data) is returning the data in exact the same format:

[image]

[image]

What am i doing wrong here? Any pointers?

Comment: try setting  $scope.data in your service success callback  as `$scope.data = response.data`

Comment: doesn't $http.get return a promise? if so, populatedata is returning the unresolved promised but not the data from the request

Comment: believe the issue is with the `return $http` since `$http` returns promises. Try removing the return and/or binding the response data to a `$scope` variable `.then(function(response) { $scope.someVariable = angular.copy(response.data); });`

Comment: thanks all. I am trying all these options.

Comment: worked ! 
I change one line 
return response; 
to 
$scope.data = angular.copy(response.data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following all the comments, this solution worked for me.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'bulletChart',
                transitionDuration: 500,
            }
        };

        $scope.data = populateData();
        function populateData(){

            $http.get('http://10.20.26.90:5003/bullet').then(function(response) {
                    console.log('response-dataFound',response.data);
                    $scope.data = angular.copy(response.data); 
                  ;})

                }

});
```

Do let me know if you think of a better approach.